# Loading scss files conditionally in Angular 8

Tags: angular, sass

all
I have an Angular application and I am using SCSS for styling. There is a variables.scss file which contains SCSS variables which are being used within all other scss files. Now, I want to change structure of the web app. When normal user logs in he/she should see normal design. But for admin I want to change the colors to something different. So what I want is to create another variables file and load it conditionally based on used type. How can I realize it?

Comment: have a look at this article, you can change themes dynamically using mixins https://medium.com/@dmitriy.borodiy/easy-color-theming-with-scss-bc38fd5734d1

Comment: With Angular theming I can only change 3 colors. However, I have a variables file which contains about 15 colors which is used through the app.

Comment: there is no limit on the number and I shared complete scss theming guide and you can keep n number  of variables.

Answer (score -1):

I have used this same condition for but did it with the [ngClass]. You can try ngClass by checking the login variable.

Comment: Of course I can. In that case I will have a lot of modification to the code. But I am looking for clean way of doing that. Like replacing one variables file.